# Magento website showing error when uploaded to Hostgator server

Tags: url, magento-1.9.2.1, hosting

i have created a website on magento1.9 platform it is running properly on my localhost Xmapp server. Now i uploaded my website data to hostgator server and made all necessary changes like nameserver pointing, local.xml file changes but still my url is showing a error. please refer my domain link. http://shopamaryllis.com/
Please guide me what i have to do. I am a new learner of website creation.

Comment: Can you post the error in your question? You can find the error from magento_root/var/reports then error log number.

Comment: a:4:{i:0;s:107:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'shopamar_admin'@'localhost' to database 'shopamar_amaryllis'";i:1;s:2573:"#0 /home/shopamaryllis/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/shopamaryllis/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/shopamaryllis/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()

Comment: Database username and password are not correct for the database you are using. Please check and update it correctly.

Comment: Hi where i can check database password. because i am uploaded dummy data base. I know my only my cpanel database user name and password.

Comment: Login to cpanel. Goto databases then check if that database is assign to any user or not. If yes then cross verify the password and username with your which you have put in local.xml

Comment: Cpanel-mysqldatabse user name password and local.xml user name password are same.

Comment: That means you have not assign the user to the database.

Comment: I already make changes in local.xml file. change the user name, password and DB name. That's the reason both are same.

Comment: Does that user have all privileges?

Comment: Yes, cpanel database user have all privileges.

Comment: Something is wrong. Can you try to create new db and new user and set all privileges to that user and then import your data to that database after assigning new db to new user.

Comment: Ok let me check